# Multiple monitors slideshow

Tags: windows-7, multi-monitor, slideshow

The people in my department and I are stumped about a good program that will manage our multiple monitors. All we really want to do is have a slideshow run. The problem it seems is that most of the solutions we find are cumbersome or only manage a few monitors. We have 5 monitors. Each are oriented landscape wise but are positioned vertically next to each other. Ideally, we'd run a slide show. Each of the 5 monitors would run a group of slides and then switch to the next group of five.

Does anyone know of software that will meet our needs?

Obviously googling has gotten us nowhere. In the past we had used QLab but we really don't want something as complicated as that.

@Jan: We have different labs. So there would be a group of slides or folder for that lab. The 5 monitors would show five slides from that lab or group. When it transitions, it would be a different group of five featuring a different lab. That is what the hope would be.

Comment: *Each of the 5 monitors would run a group of slides and then switch to the next group of five*  In sync? Please [edit] and describe exactly.

Comment: "most the solutions we find" -> which ones?

Comment: If they are in sync, isn't this just setting up the monitors as one workspace and do the slideshow in fullscreen across the monitors?

Comment: Edited for you Jan Doggen. 
Frank: 
http://www.dataton.com/watchout
http://www.intuilab.com/multi-screen-presentation-software/
http://www.nasolab.com/arraysync/
Holroy: They are already on one workspace and have extended screen. If we do a Powerpoint slideshow we can only run one instance and when we select a screen to show it on, it doesn't extend to the others.